# Generate new columns, separating by special character in multiple places within string in column (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to separate strings in a column by the hyphen in multiple places.

**Data**

```
id                      type
hello-srp-lap-555-aaa   aa
hello-sss-lap-555-aaa   vv
happy-srp-bb-578-aaa    c
```

**Desired**

```
id          type    original                  sep      sep1
hello-lap   aa      hello-srp-lap-555-aaa     hello    lap
hello-lap   vv      hello-sss-lap-555-aaa     hello    lap
happy-bb    c       happy-srp-bb-578-aaa      happy    bb
```

**Doing**

```
df[['id', 'original', 'sep', 'sep1']] = df['id'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated- The new columns are not generating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on `-`, expand  and filter the columns to take the relevant columns. Then apply `join` on the newly created columns to change `id`:

```
df['original'] = df['id']
df[['sep','sep1']] = df['id'].str.split('-', expand=True)[[0,2]]
df['id'] = df[['sep','sep1']].apply('-'.join, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
          id type               original    sep sep1
0  hello-lap   aa  hello-srp-lap-555-aaa  hello  lap
1  hello-lap   vv  hello-sss-lap-555-aaa  hello  lap
2   happy-bb    c   happy-srp-bb-578-aaa  happy   bb
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to `rsplit`

```
df[['id', 'original', 'sep', 'sep1']] = df.id.str.rsplit(n=3,pat = '-',expand=True)
df
          id type original  sep sep1
0  hello-srp   aa      lap  555  aaa
1  hello-sss   vv      lap  555  aaa
2  happy-srp    c       bb  578  aaa
```